# Docker build unable to access ADO artifacts

Tags: docker, npm, azure-devops, authorization

Using Docker locally to perform a build using my project's `.dockerfile`, I'm having trouble getting access to our private ADO Artifacts with a 401 Unauthorized.

I've generated a PAT for my ADO account with "Packaging (Read)" across all accessible organizations and it has not expired.

This works in the ADO Build Pipeline using the "npmAuthenticate" task and pointing it to the project's `.npmrc`, but locally, Docker fails to authenticate.

---

### .dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:12 AS clientBuilder
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ADD . /client
WORKDIR /client

RUN wget -qO- https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh | bash
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS '{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://<ADO FEED>/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"docker", "password":"'${NPM_TOKEN}'"}]}'

# the following line fails to authenticate
RUN npm ci
```

---

### .npmrc (project)

```sh
registry=<PROVIDED BY ADO ARTIFACTS>
always-auth=true
```

---

### Bash Command

```sh
docker build . --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=<PAT>
```

The above results in the following:

```sh
Step 9/18 : RUN echo ${VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS}
 ---> Running in 6407b058be7d
{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://*****/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"docker", "password":"*****"}]}
```

```sh
Step 11/18 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in 33a180c7b4c1
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://****, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodeus21.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-07T19_21_50_935Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What I've noticed is that if I configure the project's `.npmrc` with the same credentials as provided in my user `.npmrc`, it works fine.  Obviously I don't want the project's `.npmrc` to have any authentication information.

Please let me know if you need more information than what I've provided above.

Comment: I believe the PAT needs to be base64 encoded for NPM, but not for NuGet. You'll need to provide both a B64 encoded and non-B64 encoded PAT for both scenarios to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the base "devtools" image I've used in the past for authenticating to private Azure DevOps NuGet and NPM feeds. The PAT needs to be Base64 encoded for NPM, but not for NuGet. It's a little weird. I can't guarantee there's not a better way to do this.

```
ARG SDKVersion=3.1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:${SDKVersion} AS build-env
# Contains NPM/NodeJS for webpack and all appropriate PATs/configuration for pulling NPM and NuGet packages from private feeds
ARG NugetPAT
ARG B64PAT
ARG SDKVersion=3.1

ENV Configuration Release

ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
    "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${NugetPAT}\"}]}"
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | bash
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
    
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><packageSources><add key="public" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" /><add key="projectname-common" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/nuget/v3/index.json" /></packageSources></configuration>' > NuGet.config
RUN echo \; begin auth token > /root/.npmrc && \
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/registry/:username=orgname >> /root/.npmrc && \ 
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/registry/:_password=${B64PAT} >> /root/.npmrc && \
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn''t use the value >> /root/.npmrc && \
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/:username=orgname >> /root/.npmrc && \
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/:_password=${B64PAT} >> /root/.npmrc && \
echo //pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn''t use the value >> /root/.npmrc && \
echo \; end auth token >> /root/.npmrc
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this helped solve the problem.  I added a line to the dockerfile to convert the NPM_TOKEN argument to base64: `RUN echo -n ${NPM_TOKEN} | base64 > ~/.token64`

I then referred to that encoded token in the root `.npmrc` as you outlined, and I can now access my private ADO feed.  Thank you!

Comment: @gt-downunder Glad to help! It took me *hours* to get it working the first time. Major pain.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you a lot, i have researched everywhere and your solution work, somehow it needs your code and a separate .npmrc or else it will complain that the private package i am installing does not exist in npm registry.

Answer (score 2):

I used [@daniel-mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781754/daniel-mann) approach. I just moved away from the PAT.

Reasons why I don't use PAT:

- It expires
- Is related to a user and I neither didn't want to have it related to my account nor create a `build` user.

**The approach:**

1. Create a `.npmrc` file without a password in the root folder

**.npmrc**

```
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/registry/:username=orgname 
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but does not use the value
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/:username=orgname 
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but does not use the value
```

2. Add [npmAuthenticate@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task to inject the credentials in the `.npmrc` file

```
 task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: .npmrc
```

3. for the dockerfile I kept the same structure, just replace the .npmrc section

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG SDKVersion=3.1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:${SDKVersion} AS build-env
# Contains NPM/NodeJS for webpack and all appropriate PATs/configuration for pulling NPM and NuGet packages from private feeds
ARG NugetPAT
ARG SDKVersion=3.1

ENV Configuration Release

ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
    "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${NugetPAT}\"}]}"
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | bash
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
    
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><packageSources><add key="public" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" /><add key="projectname-common" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/projectname-common/nuget/v3/index.json" /></packageSources></configuration>' > NuGet.config

# copying the npmrc file with credentials
# don't need to authenticate as it is authenticated by 
# the npmAuthenticate task
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
```

4. Replacing the Nuget PAT to Azure System.AccessToken

```
docker build . --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)
```

the azure pipeline is something like:

```yaml
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  displayName: Authenticate .npmrc file
  inputs:
    workingFile: .npmrc

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: build container
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      docker build . --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)
```